# Select the first element in each day of the month

Tags: mysql

How to select the first element of each day in a month with mysql query ?

I have table with offers - startdate, so i can check for each day,month,year i'm getting the element but, i'm wondering how to get only the first element in each day of some month ?

Comment: How is the first element determined? Is startdate a DATETIME type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the following

- Table is called mytable
- Table has id as primary key
- Table has dt as datatime
- You want the first id of everyday in February 2012

Try this:

```
SELECT B.id FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(dt) date_dt,MIN(dt) dt
    FROM mytable
    WHERE dt >= '2012-02-01 00:00:00'
    AND   dt < '2012-03-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY DATE(dt)
) A
LEFT JOIN mytable B USING (dt);
```

If any dt has multiple B.id values try this:

```
SELECT dt,MIN(id) id
(
    SELECT B.id,B.dt FROM
    (
        SELECT DATE(dt) date_dt,MIN(dt) dt
        FROM mytable
        WHERE dt >= '2012-02-01 00:00:00'
        AND   dt < '2012-03-01 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY DATE(dt)
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN mytable B USING (dt)
) AA GROUP BY dt;
```

Comment: And there's the subquery answer.

Comment: @MarcusAdams hooray for Antipatterns !!! I like your last sentence. It's kind of like matter meets antimatter thus indexes fail to exist, or the universe blows up. Maybe I should check out the book you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `startdate` is a `DATETIME` type, and the earliest entry is the one with the earliest DATETIME value, for March, 2012:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
  ON (t2.startdate BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-02-29 23:59:59')
  AND t2.startdate < t1.startdate
WHERE (t1.startdate BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-02-29 23:59:59')
   AND t2.startdate IS NULL
```

If there are no duplicate dates, then you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

This query works by joining with any earlier record for the same month, so if nothing was joined, it's the earliest, through process of elimination.

This technique is explained in detail in the book [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

This could also be solved with subqueries, but this type of JOIN is supposed to be easier to optimize by MySQL than subqueries, which often negate the use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

without knowing the exact structure of your table something like this should work:

```
SELECT MIN(offerId) FROM offers WHERE startdate <= '2012-03-06' AND startdate >= '2012-02-06' GROUP BY date(startdate)
```

Comment: i'm selecting by - startingtime between endingtime.How it would be done the query with selector like that ?

Comment: I've added a where clause, should be self explanatory.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. MIN(offerId) will give you the lowest offerId not the offerId of the row with the lowest date. So this will work only if your offerId's are in the same order as their dates.

Comment: @Ben: yep, that was my assumption (an autoincrement which is in the same order as the date)

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a different way to skin this cat (much easier in SQL Server for once actually)

```
SELECT 
   t0.offerId
FROM 
   offers AS t0 LEFT JOIN 
   offers AS t1 ON t0.offerId = t1.offerId AND t1.startDate > t0.startDate AND 
                  (t0.startDate BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-03-01') AND
                  (t1.startDate BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-03-01')
WHERE 
  t1.col1 IS NULL;
```

If you have multiple rows with the same exact time you will get multiple values returned, which you can weed out in your application logic or with a sub-query. BTW this is called a groupwise minimum/maximum.

Comment: Ben, please take a look at my earlier answer. :)

Comment: heh, didn't notice. Nice answer :-D

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do something like the following:

```
SELECT col_1, date_col, col_3 FROM tbl
WHERE
   date_col = ( SELECT min(date_col) FROM tbl
                  WHERE
                       year(date_col) = 2006 AND
                       month(date_col) = 02
               );
```

This can also be used to find the `max( date_col )` . Hope this helps.